# This query is providing an error. Can you provide an answer to this?

Tags: sql, database

```
Select a.PatientId,a.name as PatientName,c.treatmentDescription as TreatmentName
FROM patient as a inner join patient-treatment as b
on a.patientID = b.PatientID
INNER JOIN Treatment as c
ON b.TreatmentCode = c.TreatmentCode
WHERE a.address = "Woodstock" OR "Roswell";
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  It would be helpful to show us the error, no? And tag with db platform.  thanks

Comment: Hello Ankit, welcome to Stack Overflow. You would -at least! - need to share the error message that you are getting. A database tag is also a must have: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: @OldProgrammer you wrote in your comment: _It would be helpful to show us the error, no?_ Ah, that's the challenge! Figure out the problem **without** seeing the error message. (You do realize I'm being sarcastic, don't you?)

Comment: Please supply a screenshot or an error message..

Answer (score 1):

This line of your query is incorrect:

```
WHERE a.address = "Woodstock" OR "Roswell"
```

It should be:

```
WHERE a.address = 'Woodstock' OR a.address = 'Roswell'
```

Alternatively you can also write it like this:

```
WHERE a.address in ('Woodstock', 'Roswell')
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is with your WHERE clause.

Try:

```
a.address = 'Woodstock' OR a.address = 'Roswell';
```

or:

```
 a.address IN ('Woodstock', 'Roswell');
```

Example:

```
Select a.PatientId,a.name as PatientName,c.treatmentDescription as TreatmentName
FROM patient as a inner join patient-treatment as b
on a.patientID = b.PatientID
INNER JOIN Treatment as c
ON b.TreatmentCode = c.TreatmentCode
WHERE a.address = 'Woodstock' OR a.address = 'Roswell';
```

Comment: I think you need to fix your **Example:**

Comment: Whoever up-voted this answer, please note that double quotes are **not** valid character literal delimiters in SQL. You have up-voted an answer containing invalid syntax.

Comment: @Abra - thanks for highlighting. I have swapped out the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Replace double quotes with single quotes.

And where clause is incorrect. It should be in the form

A.name = 'x' and a.name = 'y'.
Conditions inside filters should be Boolean in nature.

Answer (score 0):

Your where should look like:
WHERE a.Addrrss = 'Woodstock' Or a.Address = 'Roswell'